# OnPlatform inside a ResourceDictionary raises error "The property 'Default' is set more than once"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

The following snippet on my ResourceDictionary causes an XLS0501 - The Property 'Default' is set more than once when editing the file.

```
<!-- Fonte Padrao -->
<OnPlatform x:Key="DefaultFont" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <On Platform="Android" Value="Droid Sans"/>
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="MarkerFelt-Thin"/>
</OnPlatform>
```

However, if I close the file and run my solution it works just fine, even settings the correct font on my App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **"Default is set more than once"**

This is a known issue,you can ignore the "Default is set more than once" or the "Platforms is not an attachable property" because they're false errors (which is the point of this open issue, the language service should not be flagging as error). you could choose **Build** instead of **Build + IntelliSense** in the Errors output window to show the legitimate error

GitHub : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3839

Comment: does that help you ?

Comment: yes, thanks sir. I'll be tracking the issue and, for time being, change to build instead of build + intelli~